# Transactional method from class 1 calling external methods, throws error, and is not rolling back

Tags: java, transactions

I need it to rollback the entire transaction when an error is thrown, but it does not roll back, just throws the errors and continues to process.

Component Class has a transactional method with a try catch block. Within the try, two external calls are being made to two different classes. The first call (serviceA.method1) succeeds and I see the DB update. The second one fails. Adding @Transactional to the other methods in the other classes does not seem to be working either.

I am under the impression that unless specifically stated, when transactionMethod instantiates, a Transaction is created. From there, any additional calls are part of that transaction unless the method or class states otherwise with Propagation.

````
import javax.transaction.Transactional;

componentClass:
   @Transactional
   public transactionMethod() {
      try{
        serviceA.method1();
        serviceB.method2();
      } catch() {
        log.error();
      }
   }
   
serviceA:
   public method1() {
      try{
        save();
      } catch() {
        log.error();
      }
   }   
   
serviceC:
   public method2() {
      try{
        save();
      } catch() {
        log.error();
      }
   }  ```
````

Answer (score 0):

> The transaction will be rollback if an exception is thrown.

This is a correct statement, but your `method1()` and `method2()` do not throw any exceptions out of the method. In `transactionMethod` point of view, there are no exceptions propagated to me, so I can process the rest.

If you want to do it, remove your `catch` in `method1()` or `method2()`.
Or you can throw another exception like

```
try{
    save();
} catch() {
    log.error();
    throw new RuntimeException(); // here is the throw ex
}
```

Hope my explanation helps!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to throw an exception and make sure it is not being caught within the valid area of the transaction;

Another way is that you can add `@Transactional` on `methodB`; then, when the exception is thrown from `methodB` to where it is called, the transaction will roll back.

And you can set some parameters of `@Transactional`, like propagation, that will change transaction's delivery mode.